# How can I save a stream to disk in Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell

How can I save a stream to disk in Powershell? Any examples appreciated.

(For info, the stream is the return value from a WCF webservice call)

Comment: Can you please show the code you've written so far(remove anything sensitive) or give more information around what you're doing, what object you're dealing with ect..

Comment: I havent got anything yet, I'm a powershell newbie. What about an example showing opening a text file and saving the stream?

Comment: Without sounding rude or offensive, you have to put some effort into what you're trying to do before people in here can help you.

In Powershell, .Net libraries can be used, so if you're coming from a .Net background you can show what you're doing in .Net and we can help convert that to Powershell.

Also, what is been returned from the WCF webservice call? Is it a FileStream object? MemoryStream? Plain text?

Comment: I appreciate that. I'm not looking for handholding, just a link to a tutorial or a quick cut and paste example..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, it is useful to Google how to do the thing with C#. Conversion from C# to Powershell is IMHO more easy than from VB.Net, as PowerShell's syntax is a bit similar. From any C# examples, one can easy find out what .Net classes are used and how. Armed with that knowledge, transforming the techniques into Powershell is quite straightforward.

First off, get the data to a variable. Create a FileStream that points to a file. Create a StreamWriter that usest the file stream and write data into it. Like so,

```
$webPage = [Net.WebClient]::DownloadString("http://www.google.com") # Sample data
$fs = new-object IO.FileStream("c:\temp\out.txt", [IO.FileMode]::Append) # New FileStream to some file
$sw = new-object IO.StreamWriter $fs # A streamwriter will write to the file via filestream above
$sw.WriteLine($webPage) # Write stuff to the file via streamwriter
$sw.Close() # Close writer
$fs.Close() # Close stream
```

Comment: @vonPryz 's solution works nicely and I've used it myself. I also just discovered that the New-Item cmdlet will do the same, for example: New-Item -ItemType file -Path "c:\temp" -Name "out.txt" -Value $webPage -Force   (-Force will force overwriting file, if it exists already)